# Parsing rekognition get_face_search results

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, amazon-rekognition

I am trying to parse out Face Matches from the results of the get_face_search() AWS Rekognition API. It outputs an array of Persons, within that array is another array of FaceMatches for a given person and timestamp. I want to take information from the FaceMatches array and be able to loop through the array of Face Matches.

I have done something similar before for single arrays and looped successfully, but I am missing something trivial here perhaps.

Here is output from API:

```
    Response:
{
  "JobStatus": "SUCCEEDED",
  "NextToken": "U5EdbZ+86xseDBfDlQ2u8QhSVzbdodDOmX/gSbwIgeO90l2BKWvJEscjUDmA6GFDCSSfpKA4",
  "VideoMetadata": {
    "Codec": "h264",
    "DurationMillis": 6761,
    "Format": "QuickTime / MOV",
    "FrameRate": 30.022184371948242,
    "FrameHeight": 568,
    "FrameWidth": 320
  },
  "Persons": [
    {
      "Timestamp": 0,
      "Person": {
        "Index": 0,
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.987500011920929,
          "Height": 0.7764084339141846,
          "Left": 0.0031250000465661287,
          "Top": 0.2042253464460373
        },
        "Face": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.6778846383094788,
            "Height": 0.3819068372249603,
            "Left": 0.10096154361963272,
            "Top": 0.2654387652873993
          },
          "Landmarks": [
            {
              "Type": "eyeLeft",
              "X": 0.33232420682907104,
              "Y": 0.4194057583808899
            },
            {
              "Type": "eyeRight",
              "X": 0.5422032475471497,
              "Y": 0.41616082191467285
            },
            {
              "Type": "nose",
              "X": 0.45633792877197266,
              "Y": 0.4843473732471466
            },
            {
              "Type": "mouthLeft",
              "X": 0.37002310156822205,
              "Y": 0.567118763923645
            },
            {
              "Type": "mouthRight",
              "X": 0.5330674052238464,
              "Y": 0.5631639361381531
            }
          ],
          "Pose": {
            "Roll": -2.2475271224975586,
            "Yaw": 4.371307373046875,
            "Pitch": 6.83940315246582
          },
          "Quality": {
            "Brightness": 40.40004348754883,
            "Sharpness": 99.95819854736328
          },
          "Confidence": 99.87971496582031
        }
      },
      "FaceMatches": [
        {
          "Similarity": 99.81229400634766,
          "Face": {
            "FaceId": "4699a1eb-9f6e-415d-8716-eef141d23433a",
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.6262923432480737,
              "Height": 0.46972032423490747,
              "Left": 0.130435005324523403604,
              "Top": 0.13354002343240603
            },
            "ImageId": "1ac790eb-615a-111f-44aa-4017c3c315ad",
            "Confidence": 99.19400024414062
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": 66,
      "Person": {
        "Index": 0,
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.981249988079071,
          "Height": 0.7764084339141846,
          "Left": 0.0062500000931322575,
          "Top": 0.2042253464460373
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": 133,
      "Person": {
        "Index": 0,
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.9781249761581421,
          "Height": 0.783450722694397,
          "Left": 0.0062500000931322575,
          "Top": 0.19894365966320038
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": 199,
      "Person": {
        "Index": 0,
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.981249988079071,
          "Height": 0.783450722694397,
          "Left": 0.0031250000465661287,
          "Top": 0.19894365966320038
        },
        "Face": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.6706730723381042,
            "Height": 0.3778440058231354,
            "Left": 0.10817307233810425,
            "Top": 0.26679307222366333
          },
          "Landmarks": [
            {
              "Type": "eyeLeft",
              "X": 0.33244985342025757,
              "Y": 0.41591548919677734
            },
            {
              "Type": "eyeRight",
              "X": 0.5446155667304993,
              "Y": 0.41204410791397095
            },
            {
              "Type": "nose",
              "X": 0.4586191177368164,
              "Y": 0.479543000459671
            },
            {
              "Type": "mouthLeft",
              "X": 0.37614554166793823,
              "Y": 0.5639738440513611
            },
            {
              "Type": "mouthRight",
              "X": 0.5334802865982056,
              "Y": 0.5592300891876221
            }
          ],
          "Pose": {
            "Roll": -2.4899401664733887,
            "Yaw": 3.7596628665924072,
            "Pitch": 6.3544135093688965
          },
          "Quality": {
            "Brightness": 40.46360778808594,
            "Sharpness": 99.95819854736328
          },
          "Confidence": 99.89802551269531
        }
      },
      "FaceMatches": [
        {
          "Similarity": 99.80543518066406,
          "Face": {
            "FaceId": "4699a1eb-9f6e-415d-8716-eef141d9223a",
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.626294234234737,
              "Height": 0.469234234890747,
              "Left": 0.130435002334234604,
              "Top": 0.13354023423449180603
            },
            "ImageId": "1ac790eb-615a-111f-44aa-4017c3c315ad",
            "Confidence": 99.19400024414062
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": 266,
      "Person": {
        "Index": 0,
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.984375,
          "Height": 0.7852112650871277,
          "Left": 0,
          "Top": 0.19718310236930847
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

I have isolated the timestamps (just testing my approach) using the following:

```
timestamps = [m['Timestamp'] for m in response['Persons']]
Output is this, as expected - [0, 66, 133, 199, 266]
```

However, when I try the same thing with FaceMatches, I get an error.

```
[0, 66, 133, 199, 266]
list indices must be integers or slices, not str: TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 40, in lambda_handler
    matches = [m['FaceMatches']['Face']['FaceId'] for m in response['Persons']]
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 40, in <listcomp>
    matches = [m['FaceMatches']['Face']['FaceId'] for m in response['Persons']]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What I need to end up with is for each face that is matched:

```
Timestamp
FaceID
Similarity
```

Can anybody shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your needs , you have two FaceMatch objects in your response and you can extract required info in this way :

```
import json 

with open('newtest.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

length =len(data['Persons'])


for i in range(0,length):
    try:
        print(data['Persons'][i]['FaceMatches'][0]['Similarity'])
        print(data['Persons'][i]['FaceMatches'][0]['Face']['FaceId'])
        print(data['Persons'][i]['Timestamp'])
    except:
        continue
```

I have taken your json object in **data** variable and i have ignored **timestamps** where there is no corresponding **facematch**, if you wish you can extract then the same way

Comment: Thank you Mausam. For my example what do i need to replace for ‘newtest.json’?

Comment: I think you are storing your result from api call in **response**  variable, so just ignore 3 and 4th lines, and replace **data** with response everywhere.

example, change line 6 to
**length=len(response['Persons'])** 

or you can just change your response variable to **data** variable , ignore 3,4  line and enjoy rest of code

Comment: Perfection. Thank you sir!

Comment: Hi Mausam. Sorry for the follow up - just a quick question. How can I find the length of FaceMatches outside the loop?

Comment: can you clarify more , what are you asking about ?

Comment: Sure. So in the previous post where you got the element at '['Persons'][i]['FaceMatches'][0]['Face']['FaceId'])', for each person element, I need to be able to see if there was a Face Match found. That needs to happen outside the for loop, otherwise the loop fails when no matches are found. Checking to see if there is FaceMatches allows me to add an IF condition before I insert results to database. So is there something similar to the length check of Persons array that can be done for FaceMatches before beginning the loop. Does that help clarify?

Comment: What you want to do is already happening in the loop , the results are only generated if and only if there is a facematch for a person , if there is no facematch in a particular iteration , then it produces an exception which i have handled with using **continue** statement and skipping that iteration, what you can do is just handle the exception as you want to do ;)

Comment: By the way , the length can be checked in this way for Facematches ,
**length=len(data['Persons'][i]['FaceMatches'])**  where **i** represents a particular person

Comment: Thanks Mausam, you are very helpful.

Comment: just one thing, using the  **length=len(data['Persons'][i]['FaceMatches'])** where **i** represents a particular person - this will only work in the same for loop right?

Comment: but while its in the loop, it will add a record for exception where it finds no face matches - hence why I need to do it outside the loop.

Comment: can you show me your code ? then only i can suggest further

Comment: Too long for comments, please see codeshare link - formatting is off so please ignore that :-)

[codeshare link is here](https://codeshare.io/2KQoOz)