# AWS Rekognition "response['FaceDetails']"

Tags: python, list, amazon-web-services, dictionary, boto3

I am running into an issue with AWS Rekognition python API. The interesting part is that the issue I'm encountering seems to only affect the `response = client.detect_faces`API as the problem doesn't occur with `response = client.detect_labels`. What I'm trying to do is to filter out only the information that I want to use in the next parts of my program. This works fine for the label detection with this code:

```
labels1=response['Labels']
extractor=len(labels1)
for i in range(0,extractor):
    print(labels1[diction_counter])
    diction_counter += 1
diction_counter=0
```

A similar code defines `labels1` as a list which includes all FaceDetails:

```
labels1=response['FaceDetails']
```

When printing that list it displays a huge block of information and that is what it should do at this moment. However, when requesting the length of the list,

```
print(len(labels1))
```

The answer I am receiving is 1
At this point, the problems I am encountering are starting. According to the response structure for FaceDetection found in the [AWS Boto 3 docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.detect_faces), the response structure of `FaceDetails`is separated into 15 dictionaries which then contain the information I'm after. However, I am unable to separate the dictionaries using the method that worked for the DetectLables function:

```
extractor=len(labels1)
for i in range(0,extractor):
    print(labels1[diction_counter])
    diction_counter += 1
```

The reason for this is that python sees the response as a list with the length 1 and therefore displays everything again. The output looks like this:

```
[{'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.23359374701976776, 'Height': 0.41527777910232544, 
'Left': 0.484375, 'Top': 0.125}, 'AgeRange': {'Low': 12, 'High': 22}, 'Smile': 
{'Value': False, 'Confidence': 99.90431213378906}, 'Eyeglasses': {'Value': 
False, 'Confidence': 99.99996185302734}, 'Sunglasses': {'Value': False, 
'Confidence': 98.4183578491211}, 'Gender': {'Value': 'Male', 'Confidence': 
99.9287338256836},...
```

I've tried several things such as converting all of this into a string and then into a list which is separated by commas but nothing has worked. If anybody has an idea on how I can extract certain information so that the output looks like this:

```
'AgeRange': {'Low': 12, 'High': 22},
'Smile':{'Value': False, 'Confidence': 99.90431213378906},
'Eyeglasses': {'Value': False, 'Confidence': 99.99996185302734},
'...
```

I would greatly appreciate any tips and tricks on how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? For example, when you call `detect_faces()`, what response element do you want to extract? Also, here's some sample code using `detect_faces()`: [Send multiple frame to AWS rekognition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50742458/174777)

Comment: Can you please post one complete response, and what you want?

Comment: see if this can help you     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498421/parsing-rekognition-get-face-search-results/50527504#50527504

Answer (score 0):

You're not accessing the variables correctly

> DetectFaces detects the 100 largest faces in the image.

so you can do a for loop to access each of the faces like so:

```
response = client.detect_faces()
for faceDetail in response['FaceDetails']:
    box = faceDetail['BoundingBox'] #to get the whole bounding box.
    width = imgWidth * box['Width'] #the width of the bb.
    print('the detected face is between ' + str(faceDetail['AgeRange']['Low']) + ' and' + str(faceDetail['AgeRange']['High']) + ' years old') #access age range low & high
```

The response syntax is this:

```
{
   "FaceDetails": [ 
      { 
         "AgeRange": { 
            "High": number,
            "Low": number
         },
         "Beard": { 
            "Confidence": number,
            "Value": boolean
         },
         "BoundingBox": { 
            "Height": number,
            "Left": number,
            "Top": number,
            "Width": number
         },
         "Confidence": number,
         "Emotions": [ 
            { 
               "Confidence": number,
               "Type": "string"
            }
         ],
         "Eyeglasses": { 
            "Confidence": number,
            "Value": boolean
         },
         "EyesOpen": { 
            "Confidence": number,
            "Value": boolean
         },
         "Gender": { 
            "Confidence": number,
            "Value": "string"
         },
         "Landmarks": [ 
            { 
               "Type": "string",
               "X": number,
               "Y": number
            }
         ],
         "MouthOpen": { 
            "Confidence": number,
            "Value": boolean
         },
         "Mustache": { 
            "Confidence": number,
            "Value": boolean
         },
         "Pose": { 
            "Pitch": number,
            "Roll": number,
            "Yaw": number
         },
         "Quality": { 
            "Brightness": number,
            "Sharpness": number
         },
         "Smile": { 
            "Confidence": number,
            "Value": boolean
         },
         "Sunglasses": { 
            "Confidence": number,
            "Value": boolean
         }
      }
   ],
   "OrientationCorrection": "string"
}
```

you can access other variables with something like:

```
emotions = faceDetail['Emotions']

print('Emotion: ' + emotions[0]['Type']) #emotions[0] is for the first face, emotions[1] for the second and so on.
```